# Find the matrix for the linear projection onto a subspace with respect to the direct sum of the two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a homework problem from a PhD course in Regression Theory from the Statistics department.

Q. Find a matrix representation for the linear projection onto the two subspaces $V_1$, $V_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the direct sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$ = $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I approached this by first getting an idempotent matrix so that I can get a linear projection. However, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: That's all you need. two matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that  they are indempotent and the image of $P_i$ is $V_i$.

Comment: “... with respect to the direct sum of $V_1$ and $V_2$” suggests to me that the kernel of the projection onto $V_1$ must be $V_2$ and vice-versa. Is that a correct interpretation?